# Laravel Asset Pipeline Concatenates Assets in Local Environment

Tags: php, laravel, asset-pipeline, local

I've [logged an issue](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline/issues/199) about this in GitHub.

I've confirmed that my Laravel environment is set to `local`, but the asset pipeline still concatenates all of my assets into my two application.js and application.css files.

Has anyone else run into this in Laravel 4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, I needed to remove `local` from the `concat` setting in the codesleeve `config` file.

```
'concat' => array('production', 'local'),
```

should be

```
'concat' => array('production'),
```

I think most developers would, by default, prefer not to concatenate files in development mode, which is I think where the confusion came from.